# Output multiple React apps from one Webpack config

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-portal

I'm working on a web app that has a companion WordPress site. Let's assume domains like:

- `app.site.com`
- `blog.site.com`

What I'd like to do is have my webpack 4 configuration output the `bundle.js` but *also* generate something like `header.js` that includes a single `<Header />` component (not the complete app).

Then I'd add a script tag to `blog.site.com` like so:

```
<script src="https://app.site.com/build/header.js" />`
```

and expect it to mount the **app's** `<Header />` in the **blog's** `#dom-element`

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the another entry point for header component. Quoting from webpack [docs](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/output#multiple-entry-points):

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    bundle: './src/app.js',
    header: './src/header.js'
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: __dirname + '/build'
  }
};
```

This will create `bundle.js` from your inital entry point. And also `header.js` from the Header component.

Comment: My guess would be the `[name]` part in `output.filename`. That `name` refers to the entry point. Not the entry filename. I mess up a lot there too. :)